# Can I import ES Modules from other <script type="module">

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

I want to import from another script tag.

```
<script type="module">
    export default "str"
</script>

<script type="module">
    import foo from "????"
    console.log(foo) // str
</script>
```

What should I write in "???"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible. A ModuleSpecifier (what comes after the `from`) must be a string, and needs to point to a *standalone JavaScript file* with exports. It can't reference another script tag on the page, only a file.

Usually, a `<script type="module">` on the page itself is only used *once*, and is used to call other modules. For example, rather than your original code, you'd usually see or have something like:

```
<script type="module">
    import foo from "str.js"
    console.log(foo) // str
</script>
```

```
// str.js
export default "str"
```

Answer (score 5):

The Best answer is right, it's not possbile. But there is `import()` function
that can import es module from a url. And the `URL.createObjectURL()` method
would create a url by javascript source code. So the workaround is:

```html
<!-- Avoid executing the code below by add type=text/template -->
<script type="text/template" id="test">
  export default 'foo';
</script>
<script type="module">
  const test = await import(
    URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob(
        [document.getElementById('test').innerText],
        {type: 'application/javascript'},
      )
    )
  );
  console.log(test.default);
</script>
```

Comment: This is an interesting technique. I moved your code into a snippet so that others can run it and see that it works.